# Iterating through and adding multiple Json files to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So my question is this. I have these JSON files stored in a list called `json_list`

```
['9.json',
 '8.json',
 '7.json',
 '6.json',
 '5.json',
 '4.json',
 '3.json',
 '2.json',
 '10.json',
 '1.json',]
```

Each of these files contains a dictionary with an (ID NUMBER: Rating).

This is my code below. The idea is to store all of the keys and values of these files into a dictionary so it will be easier to search through. I've separated the keys and values so it will be easier to add into the dictionary. The PROBLEM is that this iteration only goes through the file '1.json' and then stops. I'm not sure why its not going through all 10.

```
for i in range(len(json_list)):
    f = open(os.path.join("data", json_list[i]), encoding = 'utf-8')
    file = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = json.loads(file)
    keys = data.keys()
    values = data.values()
```

Comment: How do you know that it only goes through `1.json`? I think the problem lies in your expectation, not the actual result. Do these files contain the same keys by any chance? *(Also, you can just do `for filename in json_list` to get the filename from the list, you don't have to do `json_list[i]`)*

Comment: I get the same answer. And to answer your previous question, I just checked. I ran another cell where I only opened '1.json' and the results matched.

Comment: can you show us how the JSON looks? at least the 1 and 2.

Comment: do you want to create dictionary or just trying to get keys and values from all the json files

Comment: @DevanJoshi My suspicion is that you don't fully understand how `data.keys()` are stored and how to work with the data. Because your code, technically works just fine. Try doing `print(i)` at the top of the loop and you'll see that all files are loaded. But as answered below, you replace all previous iteration with the next loop's data. Meaning, the last result/file will be the only data you actually keep, as it gets overwritten each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
data = json.loads(file)
keys = data.keys()
values = data.values()
```

You're resetting the value for keys and values instead of appending to it.

Maybe try appending them, something like (The dictionary keys MUST be unique in each file or else you'll be overwriting data):

```
data = json.loads(file)
keys += list(data.keys())
values += list(data.values())
```

**Or better yet just append the dictionary (The dictionary keys MUST be unique in each file or else you'll be overwriting data):**

```
all_data = {}
for i in range(len(json_list)):
    f = open(os.path.join("data", json_list[i]), encoding = 'utf-8')
    file = f.read()
    f.close()
    data = json.loads(file)
    all_data = {**all_data, **data}
```

Working example:

```
import json
ds = ['{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}','{"aa":"11","bb":"22","cc":"33", "dd":"44"}','{"foo":"bar","eggs":"spam","xxx":"yyy"}']
all_data = {}
for d in ds:
    data = json.loads(d)
    all_data = {**all_data, **data}

print (all_data)
```

Output:

```
{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c', 'aa': '11', 'bb': '22', 'cc': '33', 'dd': '44', 'foo': 'bar', 'eggs': 'spam', 'xxx': 'yyy'}
```

If the keys are not unique try appending the dictionaries to a list of dictionaries like this:

```
import json
ds = ['{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}','{"aa":"11","bb":"22","cc":"33", "dd":"44"}','{"dd":"bar","eggs":"spam","xxx":"yyy"}']
all_dicts= []
for d in ds:
    data = json.loads(d)
    all_dicts.append(data)

print (all_dicts)
# to access key
print (all_dicts[0]["1"])
```

Output:

```
[{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}, {'aa': '11', 'bb': '22', 'cc': '33', 'dd': '44'}, {'dd': 'bar', 'eggs': 'spam', 'xxx': 'yyy'}]
a
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I did try that actually, and the operands '+=' don't work for the keys and values:/

Comment: @DevanJoshi Yes it' has to be converted to list. But it much better if you just add the dictionaries directly. I updated my answer, see code.

Comment: Only some of the files were transported unfortunately.

Comment: There are some keys that repeat themselves, but have different values

Comment: @DevanJoshi If you have repeating keys you cant join the dictionaries without losing values. I updated my answer and added a way to combine the file into a list of dictionaries which will preserve the dictionary with all its keys and values. If you find it helpful please upvote and set as answer. Otherwise let us know

Comment: Perfect. I will try that, thank you again. One last question, here you have ds that equals a list of dicts, but I feel like in trying to add the dicts from '1.json - 10.json', I will run into an iteration issue again.

Comment: @DevanJoshi No you won't run into an iteration problem all you're doing is loading the json data and appending to a list of dictionaries >>  data = json.loads(d)
>> all_dicts.append(data)